# Creating text field in iOS Sharing extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

I'm working on a sharing extension in iOS with Swift. In the share app, I would like to add a custom field, where the user can add text to it. I tried finding references to see how it could be done but I can't find any.

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: A sharing extension already presents an editable text view by default, so what more are you talking about here?

Comment: I want another field in the bottom of that. An editable one.

Comment: Then simply design your own interface and don't use SLComposeServiceViewController.

Comment: I thought of simply adding a configuration item. The one that lets user enter text.

Comment: Which configuration item "lets user enter text"?

Comment: That's what I wanted to know. I couldn't find anything. So I asked here.

Comment: You couldn't find anything because there isn't one. A configuration item is a button, not a text field.

Answer (score 2):

You can't magically make a text field appear in the SLComposeServiceViewController interface. So you have two choices:

- Use SLComposeServiceViewController, and add a configuration item (SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem) which you've set up so that it pushes some new interface containing a text field.

  The pushed interface is up to you, even though the SLComposeServiceViewController interface is not.
- Don't use SLComposeServiceViewController in the first place. Now the *whole* interface is up to you. Just use a normal view controller and it will be presented for you, and you can design the view in the storyboard just like always.